# Objective C - Set ImageView Width and Maintain Aspect Ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using the following animation to show a full screen image of a thumbnail onto the view:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

            [testImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, testImage.size.width, testImage.size.height)];

        }completion:^(BOOL finished){

}];
```

However, this will not contain the image within the bounds of the screen if it is a large image.

Is there a way that I can set the width of the image to the width of the screen, and adjust the image's height then to keep the proper aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the above method but with a bit more modification:

```
CGFloat verticalScale = image.height / bounds.height;
CGFloat horizontalScale = image.width / bounds.width;
CGFloat scale = max(verticalScale,horizontalScale);
CGFloat imageViewHeight = image.height / scale;
CGFloat imageViewWidth = image.width / scale;
CGRect imageViewFrame = CGRectMake(x: DESIRE_X, y: DESIRE_Y, width:imageViewWidth ,height:imageViewHeight)
imageView.frame = imageViewFrame;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect bounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
[testImageView setFrame:bounds];
testImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

But there may be some paddings if the image's scale is not equal to screen's.If you prefer the image to cover the full screen, then change contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code:

```
testImageView 
    =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y ,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height
    )]
```